# SharePoint 2016 Calculated Column Link Problem

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2016, calculated-column, jslink

Good day,

I have a project and a very tight deadline. I have developed a tool for managing events. The system was developed in SharePoint 2010 which was migrated to 2016. I used a calculated column, set it to number and added the following to create an HTML Link for my query string filter:

`=<a href='/sites/site/Pages/ManageMission.aspx?MissionID='>Manage Mission</a>`

The above created a link that navigated to a page with a query string filter and everything worked great. My platform provider upgraded to SharePoint 2016 where calculated columns can no longer render HTML/Javascript code as they used to as of 2017. Through a few days of research, I cannot find a viable solution due to the following.

-SharePoint Column Formatting is not available until O365.

-SharePoint 2007 had an old way of doing this, all solution examples do not appear to work

-SharePoint 2016 does not support the calculated column trick as 2013 did

-I have tried JSLink, however I have no knowledge of how to write in this

I find myself in the middle of multiple platforms and no viable solution. Does anyone have a solution example for this? I simply need a way to concatenate a URL with the value of MissionID Column and click on it to go to my filtered page.

R/
Cory

Comment: Have you tried returning this calculated column as **Number**? check if it working by returning the calculated column as Number or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one option to use js link.

Below is sample code on js link on converting a field data as hyper link

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
(function () {  
    // Create an object that have the context information about the fields that we want to change the rendering of.   
    var nameFiledContext = {};  
    nameFiledContext.Templates = {};  
    nameFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {  
        // Apply the new rendering for these fields on List View  
        "Name": { "View": nameFiledTemplate }  
    };  
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(nameFiledContext);  
})();  

// This function provides the rendering logic for the list view  
function nameFiledTemplate(ctx) {  
    var name = ctx.CurrentItem.Name;  

    var address = ctx.CurrentItem.Address;   
    if(address == "Hyderabad"){  
        address = "HYD";  
    }  
    else{  
        address = "BAN";  
    }  

    return "<a target='_blank' href='http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/members/ramakrishna-basagalla'>"   
        + name + " - " + address + "</a>";      
}  
</script>
```

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-make-sharepoint-field-data-as-hyper-link-using-js-link/

Comment: Thank you, I have been able to make this work.